# Why this implementation of merge sort subtract all input by 1

Tags: c

The code below is my C implementation of merge sort, but it can not work correctly, when I type `5 1 3 2 4 5` in this program, the result should be `0 1 2 3 4`, but when I enter another value in it, the result is correct. It was compiled by clang, no warning, no error. I wonder what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int nums[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int L[m - l + 1]; // include nums[m]
    int R[r - m];

    int count;
    
    for (count = 0; count < m - l + 1; ++count)
        L[count] = nums[l + count];

    for (count = 0; count < r - m; ++count)
        R[count] = nums[m + 1 + count];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = l;

    while (i < m - l + 1 && j < r - m) {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
            nums[k++] = L[i++];
        else
            nums[k++] = R[j++];
    }
    while (i < m - l + 1)
        nums[k++] = L[i++];
    while (j < r - m)
        nums[k++] = R[j++];
}

void mergeSort(int nums[], int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        mergeSort(nums, l, m);
        mergeSort(nums, m + 1, r);
        merge(nums, l, m, r);
    }
}

int main() {

    int n, i;
    int *nums;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    nums = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);

    mergeSort(nums, 0, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps ... https://ideone.com/B5MdcN

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cTczGEebo You have an access out of bounds in the line `R[count] = nums[m + 1 + count];`.

Comment: You use exclusive upper bounds, which is a good idea and also the way C organizes arrays. A range `[a, b)` has valid elements `i <= l && i < r`and a length of `b - a`. That means you sould get rid of all `+ 1`'s in your merge and sort functions. If you want, you can also assert that `k == r` after merging. ("Adjustments" like `+/-` on indices are usually a sign that you are fighting C's rage nomenclature.) But there's one place where you should put a `+ 1`, and that is when you test whether there is actually anything to sort: `if (l + 1 < r) ...`.

Comment: (a) Why is it that the result of input “5 1 3 2 4 5” should be “0 1 2 3 4”? Is it intended that the program subtract one from each input value? If not, why shouldn’t the output be “1 2 3 4 5”? State clearly and full **what the program is supposed to do**.

Comment: (b) The question states that, with the input “5 1 3 2 4 5”, the result should be “0 1 2 3 4”. That phrasing implies the result is **not** “0 1 2 3 4”. What is it? Always report the input, the desired output, and the **observed output** so people can see the difference. (It is not enough for them to run the program to see the output. Various bugs can cause their execution of the program to get different output from your execution of the program. We need to see what you see.)

Comment: (c) The question states “when I enter another value in it, the result is correct.” What is the other value? Always report **the input**, the desired output, and the observed output. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including all the missing information described in (a), (b), and (c).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `mergeSort` wrong in `main`, which leads to erratic behavior. You should have called `mergeSort(nums, 0, n-1)` instead of `mergeSort(nums, 0, n)`.

Your implementation of `mergeSort(nums, ini, end)` sorts all the elements in the interval `[ini, end]`, including both `ini` and `end` indexes. You are calling `mergeSort(nums, 0, n)`, which ends up trying to sort the element at the `n`-th index, which is out of bounds.

It is common that data in uninitialized space start off as `0`. So what is happening is not that your implementation is subtracting 1 from each element. What is happening is that the uninitialized `0` that is in "`nums[n]`" ends up being sorted into the array and the other elements are pushed one position to the side.

You will see it more clearly if you try to sort, for instance, under an input like `5 7 7 7 7 7` or `5 10 20 30 40 50` or `5 -2 -1 1 2 3`. You will see that a `0` that was not in the array ends up in the array; and the elements are ordered as if the `0` was there in the first place.

Note that uninitialized values don't always default to `0`, so the content of `nums[n]` could be any unknown value; and there are scenarios where the program would be aborted the moment it tried to access `nums[n]`, which is out of bounds.